# "Wash the sections with PBS twice 5 min each time" - is there a need for a comma?

Tags: commas

Should there be a comma before "X min each time" in sentences like:

> Wash the sections with PBS twice for 5 min each time.

I found [examples](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1avztECIyAYC&lpg=PA24&dq=%22wash%20with%20PBS%22%20%22each%20time%22&hl=ru&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=%22wash%20with%20PBS%22%20%22each%20time%22&f=false) with no comma:

> [image]

And [examples](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gtysUaeXmGYC&lpg=PA193&dq=%22wash%20with%22%20%22min%20each%20time%22&hl=ru&pg=PA193#v=onepage&q=%22wash%20with%22%20%22min%20each%20time%22&f=false) with a comma:

> [image]

Maybe it could be omitted in terse technical language? 
But in normal language, would the comma be necessary?
Would the situation be different If we used "**for** 5 min each time"?

Comment: Maybe it's just sloppy writing. Note the end of the second line of the first example: "**was** with PBS 3 times". A comma or **for** certainly improves readability.

Comment: My first thought was that 'wash' should be 'watch': “Watch the sections with [PBS](http://www.pbs.org/) twice 5 min each time”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wash the sections with PBS twice for 5 min each time.

I would say that this sentence is fine because of the use of "for." It could be written as follows, and in this example a comma is required:

> For 5 minutes each time, wash the sections twice with PBS.

As for your other sentences, I'd say that they are just poorly-written. However, in terse writing there aren't really any rules to be followed – what is written is (close to) the minimum required for understanding. The most common example of this is probably [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese):

> - Forms of the verb "to be" are omitted.
> - Articles are usually omitted.
> - Most verbs are simple present tense.
> - The future is expressed as "to" followed by a verb.
> - In the US (but not the UK), conjunctions are replaced by a comma.
> - A long word is sometimes replaced by a shorter word with not quite the same meaning.
> - Country names are often used instead of their adjective form.

If I wasn't writing them tersely, I would probably write the sentences in your question as:

> Wash the slides with PBS three more times for 5 minutes each time.
>
> Add Strepavididn HRP for one hour, then wash with PBS three times for 5 minutes each time, and then wash with deionized water for 2 minutes.
>
> Wash with PEM twice for 5 minutes each time.